# D3.JS : recover cell value when click in a row

Tags: d3.js

I have made a table from a csv with d3.js. When I click in a cell I want to get the value of the last cell in its row .

I tried this :

```
     var container = d3.select("body")
        .append("table")
        .attr("id","myTable");
        //header
        var headers=container.append("thead").append("tr")
                .selectAll("th")
                .data(titles)
                .enter().append("th")

                .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
                });
        var rows=container.append("tbody")
            .selectAll("tr").data(dataCSV)
            .enter().append("tr")
        .on('click',function(d){
                if(d3.select(this).classed("highlight")){
                d3.selectAll("tr").classed("highlight", false);
            }else{
                d3.selectAll("tr").classed("highlight", false);
                      d3.select(this).classed("highlight", true);           
            }

        });

        rows.selectAll("td")
          .data(function (d) {
            return titles.map(function (k) {
                return { 'value': d[k], 'name': k};
            });
          }).enter()
          .append('td')
          .attr("style","width:"+widthCellule+"%")
          .attr('data-th', function (d) {
            return d.name;
         })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })
```

```
    /* Here is my mistake , I d'ont know */
    .on('click',function(d,i,j){
    column=i;
    last_column=titles.length;
    alert(d3.select('id','myTable').rows[j].cells[last_column].innerHTML);

    });
```

Comment: Maybe you're just missing '-1' on your last_column index, it should be .cells[last_column-1.] Please use stackblitz or similar to make your code easily testable online, it's difficult to guess exactly what are you doing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)